# Data Extraction Tricks

Tags: excel

In an excel spreadhsheet, there are many websites that are stored along with other data. Websites URLs are scattered in different rows & columns cells, even in some cells URLs are stored with other data after space e.g.

```
A1:www.yahoo.com 
A2:www.gmail.net evening  
A3:www.google.sg morning
A4:Night
B1:www.yah.com www.goo.com
B2:Sample
```

Assuming all websites are prefixed with either `www` or suffixed with `.com` is it possible to extract only all those website URLs & store and list them into a new spreadsheet or text file?

I tried to find command, it can only list all URLs,  but it cant help to extract those URLs.

Comment: Do you want to get only the URLs into a sheet? You could perhaps use another sheet filled with formulas only and you'll get each URL in the cells that they were in the first sheet. Let me know if that suits you and I'll type up the answer. Also, is it possible to have multiple URLs in a single cell?

Comment: another sheet with filled in formulas is also OK. i can later combine or merge them to have a list in a single column/row.

Comment: yes, there are chances where multiple URLs are inside a single cell also.

One option i could think of is as under, but not sure are there any other ways out?
=IF(SEARCH("com",A1)>0,A1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can have multiple links in the cells, it might be better to use the regex capability of MS Word. What I suggest is:

1. Copy your excel sheet and paste in MS Word.
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, click on <kbd>More >></kbd>, check "User wildcards".
3. In "Find what:", put in `www\.*\.com` and click <kbd>Find in</kbd> > <kbd>Main Document</kbd>
4. Click the in the document **only once** so that you can see all the highlighted/selected URLs. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

You can then paste it wherever you need it, notepad, excel, another work document, etc.

Comment: This is a really cool trick. What if suffix is not repeating i.e. somewhere "com" or "net" or "gov" etc...

Comment: @jackopen I can't seem to find an or operator that's usually available to generic regex engines, but the most I could do was to use `www\.*\.[comnetrg]{3}` or `www\.*\.[comnetrg]{3}>` (the latter is better, but requires that there's a space after the URL, or a punctuation mark).